# I have A POST Request, Need to pass body parameters, In My Code Below

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I have **POST**  request that takes body as parameters.

[image]
I tried this, but I didn't get any Response,
Does Alamofire allow to Send body parameters when making API Requests?

```
 let params = [
            "course":"1",
            "batch":"1"
        ]


Alamofire.request(markURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
            if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                var jsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
                print(jsonVar)
            }
        }
```

I'm Kinda stuck, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to set `URLEncoding.httpBody`instead of `JSONEncoding.default`?

Comment: THANX a Lot, It worked, I was searching from yesterday

Comment: Glad i could help. I would appreciate if you accept my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your encoding like this:

```
Alamofire.request(markURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
            if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                var jsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
                print(jsonVar)
            }
        }
```